# What this Iptables rules does?

Tags: linux, iptables

I think I can understand this iptable rule, but I want to make sure what it does, so can someone explain to me technically what this does? well this two rules combined.

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -d 10.13.235.42 -j DNAT --to-destination 209.208.27.224:27279

/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 27279 -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -d 10.13.235.42 -j DNAT --to-destination 209.208.27.224:27279`

- Works with the `nat` table.
- Appends the rule to the `PREROUTING` table so that decisions made in this rule can affect what routing decision gets made.
- Strictly for connections to port 80 on `10.13.235.42` which is presumably one of this machine's IP addresses.
- Set the new destination to be port 27279 on `209.208.27.224`. If `10.13.235.42` is this machine's IP address, this is needed so that the kernel doesn't think it's the final destination for traffic. At this point the destination IP address in the incoming packet has been altered.
- `-j DNAT` just means we're NAT'ing for the destination, rather than obscuring the source of the connection from the destination (which would be `SNAT`).

> /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 27279 -j MASQUERADE

- Works with the `nat` table AFTER a routing decision has taken place.
- Matches any tcp packets destined for port `27279` to and from any IP address. I suppose the idea here is that we don't need to be too specific as that's an uncommon port number.
- Tells the kernel to `MASQUERADE` meaning that packets are being modified to obscure either source or destination. This lets response come back through the way they came.